# Secant and Bisection Method

Tags: numerical-methods

What would be the example of a function for which a Secant Method fails but Bisection Method converges (to the root). In particular, if we are checking the interval $[a,b]$, then starting points for the Secant Method are $a$ and $b$.

Comment: Both methods converge. Do they not? I took starting points for the Secant Method as (0,-1) and (1,1).

Comment: it is the same as (0,-1) and (1,1) (for the Secant Method). Bisection converges for sure, since the function is continuous and changes sign in the interval [0,1]. But, Secant Method converges as well, there is no reason why it shouldn't. I don't see how it diverges with these starting points.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find a continuously differentiable function with the following properties:

- $f(a)$ and $f(b)$ have opposite signs and
- $f'(\xi) = 0$ for a $\xi \in [a,b]$

The first point ensures that the bisection methods converges. Whereas if $f'(\xi)=0$, the secant method can fail. See [these lecture notes](http://www8.cs.umu.se/kurser/5DV005/HT11/TVB.pdf) (page 101) for an example.

Comment: Do you mean $f'(a)$ or $f'(r)$?

Comment: I mean $f'(a)=0$ (or $f'(b)=0$). Functions where the derivative vanishes at the border can cause problems for the secant method. But any $f'(y)=0$ for $y \in [a,b]$ can cause problems.

Comment: Look at the figure from the lectures notes for example. There we have $f'(x_0)=0$, which in this case causes the secant method to go into the opposite direction of where the root is